# How to find email address of users who has downloaded my application from Microsoft store?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-dev-center

How to find email address of users who has downloaded my application from Microsoft store?

One of our app was delisted by MSFT, reason:'similar to another product'.
The delisted app has many users and now we want to know their email address so that we can notify them about delisting and give them GUID codes to download another similar app for free.

Regards

Comment: The short answer, that is impossible!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about an app store/app store policy, not about programming.

Comment: @BDL, I think Neha is trying to work a solution to a problem that could exist for a variety of causes.  I vote to keep this open.